# Resampling DataFrame while keeping my other columns untouched

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset that tells me the frequency of an event for each demographic(for example, first row says there are 13 white men, who are 11 years old, in the county Alameda in the year 2006 who experienced an event). Here is the original DataFrame:

```
    Year    County  age Race Sex  freq
0   2006    Alameda 11  1    0    13
1   2006    Alameda 11  1    1    9
2   2006    Alameda 11  2    0    9
3   2006    Alameda 11  2    1    16
4   2006    Alameda 11  3    0    2
```

Now, I want to compute the 2 year average of the "freq" column, by the demographic. This is the code I tried and the output:

```
dc = dc.dropna()
dc['date'] = dc.apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp('{year}'
                                .format(year=int(x.Year), 
                                        )), 
                      axis=1)
dc.set_index('date', inplace=True)
dc=dc.resample('2A', how='mean')
```

```
Date            age_range     Race      Sex          freq           
                
2006-12-31      14.507095   1.637789    0.489171    10.451830
2008-12-31      14.543697   1.664187    0.493120    10.285980
2010-12-31      14.516471   1.670205    0.489019    10.349927
2012-12-31      14.512953   1.675056    0.486677    10.109178
2014-12-31      14.568190   1.699817    0.485923    10.134186
```

It's computing the averages for each column, but how do I do it for just the freq,by the demographic cuts(like the orginal DF) column?

Answer (score 0):

Combining `groupby()` `Grouper()` and `transform()` should give you a series you want.   Your sample data set does not have enough data to demonstrate.

```
dc = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""    Year    County  age Race Sex  freq
0   2006    Alameda 11  1    0    13
1   2006    Alameda 11  1    1    9
2   2006    Alameda 11  2    0    9
3   2006    Alameda 11  2    1    16
4   2006    Alameda 11  3    0    2"""), sep="\s+")

dc["date"] = pd.to_datetime(dc["Year"], format="%Y")
dc["freq_2y"] = dc.groupby(["County","age","Race","Sex",
                            pd.Grouper(key="date", freq="2A", origin="start"),])["freq"].transform("mean")
```

|  | Year | County | age | Race | Sex | freq | date | freq_2y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2006 | Alameda | 11 | 1 | 0 | 13 | 2006-01-01 00:00:00 | 13 |
| 1 | 2006 | Alameda | 11 | 1 | 1 | 9 | 2006-01-01 00:00:00 | 9 |
| 2 | 2006 | Alameda | 11 | 2 | 0 | 9 | 2006-01-01 00:00:00 | 9 |
| 3 | 2006 | Alameda | 11 | 2 | 1 | 16 | 2006-01-01 00:00:00 | 16 |
| 4 | 2006 | Alameda | 11 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 2006-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 |

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got this error:TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'origin'
What does the origin="start" do?

Comment: what version of pandas are you using? `pd.__version__` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html this param is new in 1.1.0